# Unable to connect to sqlplus which is located on another server

Tags: python, sqlplus, cx-oracle

I have sqlplus installed in one of my working servers.
I installed python,cx_oracle lib in my local systems.
Now, i am trying to connect to that sqlplus and execute some queries through cx_oracle lib.

When i am trying to execute program, it is getting terminated without any error

could someone suggest any idea, how to connect to that sqlplus

please find below code i tried

def SQLCON():
    Connstr = 'username/password@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.2)(PORT = 10))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = NAME)))'

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(Connstr)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from dual')
conn.close()
```

SQLCON()

Expected : It should connect to sqlplus and retrieve results

Actual : Program is getting terminated without any results or error

Comment: SQL\*Plus is a tool that connects to an Oracle Database.  cx_Oracle is an API that lets Python applications connect to an Oracle Database.  You don't connect "to that sqlplus" - you connect from SQL\*Plus or cx_Oracle to a database.  On your "working server" what connection command or syntax do you use?

Comment: I am using "sqlplus username/password" to connect my database

Comment: When you run that exact SQL\*Plus command on a non-working machine, what error do you get?